# CartThrob Redeeming Gift Certificates doesn't work return white page error

Tags: cartthrob

Cartthrob dedicated form for redemption doesn't work, it returns white page when submitting with the form a gift certificate code in the field, also balance isn't redempt in backend

Answer (score 0):

A white page is generally a sign of a PHP error. Can you turn on PHP error output in your ExpressionEngine config and see what the error is?